# Remove/Disable hot corner

Tags: gnome3, gnome-classic

I have installed CentOS 7 which uses gnome classic, and am finding the hot corner extremely painfully annoying.

How do I remove/disable it?

Answer (score 14):

Install the extension [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/).

You can do this from your browser, visiting https://extensions.gnome.org/ . You'll need to allow the appropriate plugin to run (on Firefox, it's the plugin Gnome Shell Integration).

Comment: I get a message saying We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, you need to install first the plugin Gnome Shell Integration. This will allow you to install, enable, and disable Gnome extensions directly from Firefox.

Comment: I can't install that plugin because CentOS 7 has an old version of firefox.

Comment: Then you should update Firefox. This is also important to fix security vulnerabilities in previous versions of the browser.

Comment: I too received the "cannot detect a running copy of GNOME..." message. But when I clicked the "Allow" button and reloaded the page, the error message was gone and I could turn on the extension. And my nightmare, finally, was at an end.

Answer (score 5):

It's insane that you need to install an extension just to disable such an annoying "feature". But at least, you don't really need to go the even crazier route of first installing a browser extension, as was apparently the case in 2015.

This should work:

```
sudo yum -y install gnome-shell-extension-no-hot-corner
```

Then use the Gnome Tweak Tool to enable the "No topleft hot corner" extension.

Comment: Do you need to log out/in to activate this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `awk` 'one-liner':

```bsh
awk '/this._corner = new Clutter.Rectangle/,/ });/ { sub(/reactive: true/, "reactive: false");} { print }' /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js > /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js.tmp;
mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js.orig
mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js.tmp /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js
```

#### Source:

[Gnome3: Disable Hot Corners | IT From All Angles](https://web.archive.org/web/20150903003021/http://blog.allanglesit.com/2012/03/gnome3-disable-hot-corners/)
(Archived copy by [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) on 2015 September)

Comment: As of `gnome-shell  3.12` all the js and css files are wrapped up in resources and included in the gnome-shell binary (`/usr/lib64/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so`) so this won't work for newer versions of gnome-shell.