# Gnome 3: How to disable inner hot corners when using multiple monitors?

Tags: debian, gnome3, gnome-shell

Using Debian buster and Gnome 3.

I have two displays, then 8 corners.

```
1------2|3-----4
|       |      |     
|       |      |
5------6|7-----8
```

The hot corners launching the activities menu are 1 and 3 and it results annoying. Is there a way to disable 3 but not 1? The extensiont hot-corn-dog only has four corners, so each monitor have the same individual behavior even though they make up and extended screen.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196541/remove-disable-hot-corner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove/Disable hot corner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196541/remove-disable-hot-corner)

Comment: Does the suggested duplicate disable all hot corners or just the ones that aren't corners (as it were)?

Comment: @Francisco This disables the hot corner, but it does the same in all the monitors. So by disabling top left, I am disabling 1) and 3). Which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Then I suppose you could have a look at the code for that extensions and change it to fit what you want... other than that, I don't think GNOME permits it out-of-the-box, sadly.